# git unable to rm --cached files

Tags: git

I want to remove all my *.pyc files from version control. I've tried `git rm -r cached ./*.pyc` but I got the error `fatal: pathspec 'widgets.pyc' did not match any files`. I thought `widgets.pyc` is not in version control but `git status widgets.pyc` says that my file is on `branch master`.

Any remedy for my problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try `git rm -r --cached ./\*.pyc` (note the backslash character before the asterisk) to ensure your command shell passes the wildcard character to git instead of expanding it itself.